# another .htaccess url rewriting issue

Tags: php, url-rewriting, apache2

I've got a site that I am developing locally on wampserver, and I'm using url rewriting in an .htaccess file.  I've tried all of the following:

1. mod_rewrite is enabled
2. httpd.conf has AllowOverride All for the directory ("C:\wamp\www\pascale3")

Here is my .htaccess file, it is in this directory( "C:\wamp\www\pascale3")

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(about|mission|contact)/?$ index.php?p=$1

</IfModule>
```

This is the url I am trying to rewrite:

```
http://local.pascale3.com/?p=about
```

I also have a godaddy live site and it doesn't work there either

Comment: You're aware that RewriteRules are for incoming URLs, not rewriting existing ones? What error are you getting? Also please try to come up with a descriptive/summarative question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess rule with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# to externally redirect /index.php?p=about to /about
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php)?\?p=(about|mission|contact)[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# to internally forward /about to /index.php?p=about
RewriteRule ^(about|mission|contact)/?$ /index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Yes L for Last, QSA for Query String Append and NC for No (ignore) case comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this index.php to debug

```
<?php
    echo('<pre>');
    print_r($_SERVER);
    print_r($_GET);
    die;
```

See if you are getting something like, when going to
http://local.pascale3.com/contact

```
Array(
    ......
    [QUERY_STRING] => p=contact
    [REQUEST_URI] => /contact
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [argv] => Array
        (
            [0] => p=contact
        )

    [argc] => 1
)
Array
(
    [p] => contact
)
```

If you don't see that p param, then there's a server config/htaccess issue. Check also whether index.php?p=contact works at all. And you see the above debug info.

Comment: there is no p param, that's weird, why wouldn't wampserver accept a get variable

Comment: nevermind it is getting the GET variables, I was not adding the rewrite flags.